# How do I bundle a python interpreter in my qml app?

Tags: application-development, python, programming, qml, click-packages

How do I bundle a python interpreter in my qml app? I can not use the system's python interpreter due to the nature of Ubuntu’s new Click Packages, and App-Armour.

How do I do this?

Comment: I think you may have better luck asking programming and development questions at http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @ElderGeek QML Questions, particularly ones having to do with specific ubuntu technologies such as Click Packages, makes this on topic. You only bundle a python interpreter because of App Armor and the Click Package.

Comment: Development on Ubuntu is on-topic. References: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5744 and http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6554

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/foundations-1305-click-package. Is this truly for Ubuntu? " When using the Ubuntu SDK you would expect the base system to include the dependencies you need.
- any dependancies you do need you will include, though most libraries are not amenable to this usage"